# If Selenium driver does not find Element ( If - else if) move on, yet it throws a can't find element error

Tags: java, selenium, chromium

Long story short - I have a button that doesn't have ID's and has a compound class( So selenium hates it / cant find it). So I use the XPath selector for it that works great

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue to Payment']")).click()
```

But the button changes depending on the language being used.

So at the moment, I have

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue to Payment']")).isDisplayed()){ 
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue to Payment']")).click();
    }

else if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Paiement']")).isDisplayed()){           
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Paiement']")).click();
    }

else if ( same thing as above but for another language)
```

But when Selenium errors out after going through the first if statement with:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Checkout')]"}
```

I know the element is not there.. so I dont want it to do anything & move on to the next if else statement.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you're missing try/catch.  You can also just grab a list by using findElements.  If the list size is >0 you have found it.... something like this:     wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ec_Timeout);
        List<WebElement> element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(your_xpath)));    if (element.size() > 0) {....}  (But you should still use try/catch...) the wait will throw timeout...

Comment: Share HTML of the page, maybe there're another ways to locate input.

Comment: @pcalkins THANK YOU!! that works great to move onto the second value!!

Lets say its neither the 1st or the 2nd. and the catch will have an exception as well.

would I make it
Try {code A - not there}
catch{ other code - not there}
Try {code c}

or 
Try{ code A +Code B]
Catch{Code C}

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is initialize the List<WebElement> ahead of time.  Then perform the click on the first element if the list size is > 0 at the end... (after all elements have been found or not found... )   I suppose you could also make a function that returns the list if one item is found.  That would avoid checking for more languages if it's already found.

Comment: Do try/catch each separate findElements() call... also, you won't need the webdriverwait if the elements aren't created via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue to Payment']")).isDisplayed()){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue to Payment']")).click();
            }

            else if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Paiement']")).isDisplayed()){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Paiement']")).click();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Button not found");

        } catch(NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Impossible to click the pop-up. Reason: " + e.toString());
        }
```

Try above solution, Hopefully it will work for you. In your example wrong code has been written for `else if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Paiement']")).isDisplayed)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate short methods to achieve expected results and log errors.

```
public WebElement getElement(WebDriver driver, String XPATH, int timeoutInSeconds){
    WebElement elem = null;
    try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
        elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(XPATH));
    } catch (Exception e){
        // log or print error.
    }
    return elem;
}
```

You can then call it like

```
WebElement e = getElement(driver, "//input[@value='Continue to Payment']", 10); 
if (e != null) {
    e.click();
} else {
  e = getElement(driver, "//input[@value='Paiement']", 5);
  if (e != null) {
    e.click();
  } /// and so on....
}
```

This way you can adjust the wait time for each element and also not fall into errors if any one element is missing because of language.